# What does this GoT group do now?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of the finale of Game of Thrones,

> Jon Snow is exiled to the Night's Watch as punishment for killing Daenerys.

However given that the threat of

> the White Walkers appears to be dead for good

and

> the Wildlings are no longer in conflict with the Northmen

what is the point of this group? They no longer are needed to defend Westeros, so what do they do now?

Comment: The top answer covers this very well and I think a quote along the lines of "A place for bastards and broken things" is said in the final episode confirming it.